# Get the 5 most sold products for the past week

Tags: php, laravel

As the title states, I'm trying to get the top 5 most sold products in the past week.

In `MySQL`, I do that like so:

```
select op.id_product from order_product as op
inner join `order` as o on o.id_order = op.id_order
where o.purchase_date between date_sub(now(), interval 1 week) and now()
group by op.id_product
order by sum(op.quantity_ordered) desc limit 5;
```

Which works without a hitch. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to properly "translate it" to Laravel syntax.

I came up with this, which sort of works, but the order is wrong:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$now = $now->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');
$lastWeek = new DateTime();
$lastWeek = $lastWeek->modify('previous week');
$lastWeek = $lastWeek->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');
$orderProductIDs = DB::table('order_product')
    ->select('order_product.id_product')->join('order', 'order.id_order', '=', 'order_product.id_order')
    ->whereBetween('order.purchase_date', [$lastWeek, $now])
    ->groupBy('order_product.id_product')
    ->orderByRaw('sum(order_product.quantity_ordered) desc limit 5')
    ->get();
dd($orderProductIDs);
```

The raw SQL query produces this order of `id_product`s:  `15 2 3 12 10`

While the Laravel code outputs: `10 15 2 6 12`

So I changed things up a bit to figure out why.

```
select op.id_product, sum(op.quantity_ordered) as total from order_product as op
inner join `order` as o on o.id_order = op.id_order
where o.purchase_date between date_sub(now(), interval 1 week) and now()
group by op.id_product
order by total desc limit 5;
```

Outputs:

| id_product | total |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 12 | 2 |
| 10 | 1 |

```
$orderProductIDs = DB::table('order_product')
    ->selectRaw('order_product.id_product, sum(order_product.quantity_ordered) as total')
    ->join('order', 'order.id_order', '=', 'order_product.id_order')
    ->whereBetween('order.purchase_date', [$lastWeek, $now])
    ->groupBy('order_product.id_product')
    ->orderByRaw('total desc limit 5')
    ->get();

/* Generated Query using 'toSql()'

select order_product.id_product, sum(order_product.quantity_ordered) as total from `order_product` inner join `order` on `order`.`id_order` = `order_product`.`id_order` where `order`.`purchase_date` between ? and ? group by `order_product`.`id_product` order by total desc limit 5
*/
```

Outputs:

| id_product | total |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 4 |
| 15 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 12 | 2 |

This makes me think the problem has to do with the dates. So I made the Laravel compiler throw an error and saw the query in the browser, which had these as dates `where created_at between 2022 -07 -11 23: 07: 10 and 2022 -07 -23 23: 07: 10`, while `select date_sub(now(), interval 1 week);` outputs `2022-07-16 23:18:55`

**Questions:**

1. How do I correct the date problem?
2. Is it possible to structure the Laravel query using the `OrderProduct::all()->[etc.]` way instead of using `DB::table('order_product')->[etc.]`?

#### Edit:

##### Minimal Reproducible Example:

**Note: As I was editing my question, I realized I have a `purchase_date` column in my `Order` table, of which I had completely forgotten about (rofl). There for, I restructured my original question's code to use that instead of the `created_at` timestamp in the `OrderProduct` table for each `Product`.*

*(Do everything sequentially because there are foreign keys)*

**Console / Terminal:**

```
php artisan make:migration create_product_table
php artisan make:migration create_order_table
php artisan make:migration create_order_product_table
php artisan make:model Product
php artisan make:model Order
php artisan make:model OrderProduct
php artisan make:factory ProductFactory
php artisan make:factory OrderFactory
php artisan make:factory OrderProductFactory
php artisan make:seeder DatabaseSeeder
```

**Product Table Migration:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
  /**
   * Run the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('product', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id('id_product');
      $table->string('name);
      $table->timestamps();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Reverse the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function down()
  {
    Schema::dropIfExists('product');
  }
};
```

**Order Table Migration:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
  /**
   * Run the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('order', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id('id_order');
      $table->string('order_number')->unique();
      $table->dateTime('purchase_date');
      $table->timestamps();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Reverse the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function down()
  {
    Schema::dropIfExists('order');
  }
};
```

**OrderProduct Table Migration:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
  /**
   * Run the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id('id_order_product');
      $table->foreignId('id_order')->references('id_order')->on('order')->cascadeOnDelete();
      $table->foreignId('id_product')->references('id_product')->on('product')->cascadeOnDelete();
      $table->integer('quantity_ordered');
      $table->timestamps();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Reverse the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function down()
  {
    Schema::dropIfExists('order_product');
  }
};
```

**Product Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'product';
  protected $primaryKey = 'id_product';

  use HasFactory;
}
```

**Order Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'order';
  protected $primaryKey = 'id_order';

  use HasFactory;
}
```

**OrderProduct Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrderProduct extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'order_product';
  protected $primaryKey = 'id_order_product';

  use HasFactory;
}
```

**Product Factory:**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Product>
 */
class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
  /**
   * Define the model's default state.
   *
   * @return array<string, mixed>
   */
  public function definition()
  {
    return [
      'name' => fake()->word(),
    ];
  }
}
```

**Order Factory:**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Order>
 */
class OrderFactory extends Factory
{
  /**
   * Define the model's default state.
   *
   * @return array<string, mixed>
   */
  public function definition()
  {
    return [
      'id_user' => fake()->randomElement($users),
      'order_number' => fake()->unique()->uuid(),
      'purchase_date' => fake()->dateTime(),
    ];
  }
}
```

**Database Seeder:**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\OrderProduct;

use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
  /**
   * Run the database seeds.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function run()
  {
    $product = Product::factory(100)->create();
    $order = Order::factory(142)->create();
    $orderProduct = OrderProduct::factory(300)->create();
  }
}
```

**Note: Since the dates are randomly generated, you'll have to swap some of them *manually* by opening the database with whatever database viewer you use (e.g. DBeaver, DataGrip, Navicat, phpMyAdmin, Beekeeper Studio, etc.).*

#### Edit 2:

Using `Carbon` to generate the dates, produces the same result.

```
$now = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');
$lastWeek = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->copy()->subDays(7)->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');
```

Comment: could you post the ddl?

Comment: @BagusTesa Sorry, what's that? The `dd($orderProductIDs)`?

Comment: ddl refers to [data definition language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language). i believe have quite the experience writing [mcve] questions. fyi, you can take a peek at the generated query using `toSql()` in lavarel. start from there, compare it with the one you wanted. also, use `Carbon\Carbon` to make life easier in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to Question #1:**

I have not been generating dates properly. No wonder the generated ones for the `$lastWeek` variable were almost 2 weeks back, instead of 1.

It's as simple as:

```
$now = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');
$lastWeek = Carbon::now()->subDays(7)->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');
```

Credit to ***Bagus Tesa*** who suggested using `Carbon` - it helped figure it out easier.

**Answer to Question #2:**

```
$orderProductIDs = OrderProduct::select('id_product')
    ->join('order', 'order.id_order', '=', 'order_product.id_order')
    ->whereBetween('order.purchase_date', [$lastWeek, $now])
    ->groupBy('order_product.id_product')
    ->orderByRaw('sum(order_product.quantity_ordered) desc limit 5')
    ->get();
```